# CENTOS 7.9 install error during repo creation while using kmod-ciss driver

Tags: installation, anaconda, centos

I'm trying to install centos 7.9 on an old HP DL580 using custom cciss driver package loaded during start-up with the DD paramater to get interactive driver update.

that worked well an I see my CCISS drives BUT

if I do a netinstall I can't create a repo because anaconda tries to save the repo on my usbstick .
in  /tmp/packaging.log I find:

[Errno 14] curl#37 - "couldn't open file /run/install/DD-1/repodata/repomd.xml"

so curl tries to save it on my usb stick

how do I tell initrd where to store the repo data?
or any other hits?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

okay, as a workaround don't use USB sticks but specify the repo in the inst.dd
but still I see the issue in using a USB-stick

inst.dd=https://mirror.rackspace.com/elrepo/elrepo/el7/x86_64/RPMS/kmod-cciss-3.6.26-8.el7_8.elrepo.x86_64.rpm